# Cannot use Slf4j with lombok

Tags: java, intellij-idea, slf4j, lombok

I am trying to use project lombok to generate a logger like the example [here](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/extern/slf4j/Slf4j.html).

When I go to intelliJ, there is no code completion for the `log` I enter. I get the error below:

[image: cannot resolve method 'debug(java.lang.String')]

Code exerpt:

```
package com.example.clement.recipeproject.bootstrap;

import com.example.clement.recipeproject.domain.*;
import com.example.clement.recipeproject.repositories.CategoryRepository;
import com.example.clement.recipeproject.repositories.RecipeRepository;
import com.example.clement.recipeproject.repositories.UnitOfMeasureRepository;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class DevBootstrap implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    private UnitOfMeasureRepository unitOfMeasureRepository;
    private RecipeRepository recipeRepository;

    public DevBootstrap(CategoryRepository categoryRepository, UnitOfMeasureRepository unitOfMeasureRepository, RecipeRepository recipeRepository) {
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        this.unitOfMeasureRepository = unitOfMeasureRepository;
        this.recipeRepository = recipeRepository;
    }

    // returns List<Recipe>
    private List<Recipe> getRecipes() {

        log.debug("I am a debug message");
```

*** Update:

Added some more photos to show that the `slf4j` log is coming up, but just no appropriate methods after it.

[image]
[image]

When I jump into @Slf4j I get this.

[image]

Annotation processors turned on, but unsure if the configuration is correct.

[image]

Comment: Do you use https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin plug-in?

Comment: yeap. I also tried to reinstall / restart intellij and still same problem :(

Comment: Did you try invalidating the caches?

Comment: Unfortunately the same issue persists after cleaning the cache and restarting. I have included some more images under the 'update' section.

Comment: What happens if you Ctrl-Click on "log"?

Comment: Do you have annotations processors turned on in IntelliJ? It's a little annoying, you have to do it for every project.

Comment: If you mean find definition, I'm on a mac so I think it's cmd + click (just for future readers' benefit). I have updated the image that I get. It doesn't seem very complete...

Comment: @jcotton63 - I just uploaded an image of my annotation processors config. Not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Looks good to me. I often run into problems similar to the one you're having, and most of the time its because I've forgotten to enable annotation processing for the project. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: all goods! Thanks for giving it a go through. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Is it feasible for you to create a minimal project exhibiting the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Do you add slf4j dependencies to the build.gradle like below

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
}
```

Comment: Yes you need to add actual implementation dependancy, specially when it is NOT a Spring project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you imported the correct @Slf4 annotation from package lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j?

There is an annotation of the same name in package groovy.util.logging.Slf4j.

Comment: yeap, using the right package on line 6 above `import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;`